# Viewing Data from Custom Google Analytics Tracker

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am trying to track the usage of a custom feature on my website using Google Analytics and Custom Trackers (see: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/creating-trackers)

When I am creating the tracker, I am assigning a name like so

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-X', 'auto', 'myTrackersName');
```

I am then later setting data onto my tracker

```
ga('myTrackersName.set', {
    projectId: id
 });
```

After the use is done using the feature triggered by a save event), I then send the data to GA

```
ga('myTrackersName.send', 'event', {
  eventCategory: 'Build Sent',
  eventAction: 'Success',
  eventLabel: timeElapsed
});
```

When I sign into the GA dashboard, I can see my 'Build Sent' events with the action and label properly set, but I can not find the rest of the tracker's info. When using the Google Analytics Debug extension, I can see that all of the information is being in the request, but I can not see it in any of the reports.

Is that data viewable, or do I need to enable some other feature to get access to it? Also, is there a way to have data that is sent from 'myTrackersName' to be set aside in GA reports so that the Event Categories are related (sent by) specifically to that tracker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot make up fieldnames like "projectId" and expect them to be displayed in the standard reports.

You ca, however, create a custom dimension in the property settings/custom definitions and name it "projectId" for the interface. In the code you need to refer to it via the prefix "dimension" and the numeric index. So for the first custom dimension this would look like

```
ga('myTrackersName.set', {
    'dimension1': id
 });
```

Even so this will not be part of the standard reports by default, you need to either set this as secondary dimension or create a custom report.

Comment: So when I create a custom report, there are options for 'Add Dimensions' => 'Custom Variable (Key 1)'. Is that what would map to 'dimension1'?

Comment: Custom Variables is a remnant from the classic Analytics, don't use that. I think custom dimensions will show up only after you created them, but basically yes, that how it works. You can select dimensions via a kind of select box and once you have created it there will be a section for custom dimensions available. The interface uses a human readable name you enter when you create the dimension, however the code for data collection must use "dimension1" (and you have up to 20 custom dims per property in the free GA version).

Comment: Thanks Eike! I found where to add the custom dimensions under Admin => Custom Definitions => Custom Dimensions. This seems like it will satisfy my needs. Do you know of a way to have my custom trackers data be separate from the rest of my sites data? Or would that require creating a new property?